# Finding specific attributes in AutoCAD drawing

Tags: c#, autocad

So basically I will be given a spreadsheet with AutoCAD drawing attributes and I need to find each attribute in the AutoCAD drawing and replace its value with the one from the spreadsheet.

Is there a way to find an Attribute with a specific tag name in an AutoCAD drawing without searching every single block? Also, I am writing this in C#.

Comment: Did you get a chance to download and look at the project on github?

Comment: If the spreadsheet also includes the Handle for the Attribute &/or the block that owns it then you can get it via that Handle. Otherwise, happy hunting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you have to filter through each block and each block attribute tag to see if it has the tag you are looking for.

If you look at the project I have authored on github you will find it to be relatively simple. I created the classes specifically for issues of this sort.

http://xxzer0xx.github.io/RefCAD/

Is the link, try it out :)